# original of a clone jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to know the original element after using .clone()?
Example :

```
var clone = $("#foo").clone(false);
clone = clone.clone(false); //need it to work even if it's the clone of a clone
var foo = clone.original(); //this DOES NOT exist, but this is what i'd want. 
//foo is now $("#foo");
```

One solution :
I think that I could carry the original in a data field, but it's quite heavy.

```
var source = $("#foo");
var clone = source.clone(false);
clone.data("id", source.getAttribute("id"));
var clone2 = clone.clone(false); //need it to work even if it's the clone of a clone
clone2.data("id", clone.data("id")); //here it's simplier that it would really be, because here I know, that it's already a clone that I'm cloning...
var foo = $("#"+clone2.data("id")); //foo is now $("#foo");
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: is one extra ID quite heavy?! Really?

Comment: For your information both you have not added both `clone` and `clone2` into the DOM and even if you did, it would lead to invalid HTML unless you change their IDs. The original is therefore still the **only one in the DOM and is the one that will be selected by `$('#foo')`.

Comment: What do you need to know this for? Notice that ids in one document must be unique, btw.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I'm cloning a lot, and I'm not a big fan of carrying data in those fields.

Comment: @bergi I'm storing in mysql duplicate of some data, because right know, I can't compare if two clones have the same origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will do it

```
$.fn.original = function(){
   return $(this).data('original');
};

$.fn.cloneO = function (deep){ 
   return $(this).clone(deep).data('original', $(this).original() ? $(this).original() : $(this)); 
};
```

Then you will be able to clone an element with cloneO like

`var $clone = $('#foo').cloneO();`
and get the original like

 `var $foo = $('#foo').cloneO().original();` 
or with
 
 `var $foo = $('#foo').cloneO().cloneO().original();`

Comment: this won't work - you've added the `.original` property to a jQuery object (which is transient) and not to the new element itself.

Comment: @Alnitak: You are right. When the clone is appended to the html and a 'new' jQuery-Object for that element is created the original-function won't be available. However the code above matches the described usecase. To make this solution more general the original-function/property could be defined in $.fn-namespace.

Answer (score 0):

For to get original object from a cloned object, it needs to have some reference. As long as there is a reference, GC wont be able to garbage collect it. This is a strong reason not to have a reference to the original object.

For your purpose, to differentiate original from duplicate;

```
var original = $('body');
var clone = original.clone(false);
```

checking for selector;

```
console.log(original.selector);
=> "body"


console.log(duplicate.selector);
=> ""
```

Hope this helps. :)

Also when cloning, [this](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.clone) is what jQuery does.

Comment: isn't .selector deprecated?
I don't understand how it would work. I wanna be able to access the original with only the cloned object.

Comment: @Richard yes, it's deprecated.